# Wordpress login system for phonegap

Tags: wordpress, api, cordova

I am building phonegap application to show post and other pages. Logged in users can only access these pages. So, I am creating login system in phonegap with wordpress api. I am using `json api,json api user` for api.

After username, password entered in login form authentication cookie is generated by 'generate_auth_cookie' api and stored in local storage. It is stored as `'wordpress_logged_in_5....'=>'username|1453458845|J500gDe.....'`

I am struck here. Please tell me the next steps after this. Also I need to check the user is logged in on every api call.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR JSON API LOGIN**

Method: generate_auth_cookie

First get the nonce: `http://localhost/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=generate_auth_cookie`

Then generate cookie: `http://localhost/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?username=john&password=PASSWORD-HERE`

Method: validate_auth_cookie
It needs 'cookie' var.

```
http://localhost/api/user/validate_auth_cookie/?cookie=admin|43089754375034fjwfn39u8
```

so when user sent req. of login that time you need to create nonce and then gen. auth cookie and so on. and if all good then log in to user. and save it to your site. so once user click on logout. there session will be removed.

you can also set session from here

generate cookie for 1 minute: `http://localhost/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?username=john&password=PASSWORD-HERE&seconds=60`

60 means 1 minute.

details

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/other_notes/

OR

**TRY - WP REST API V2**

http://v2.wp-api.org/

downlaod plugin and install it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

just type `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` in end of your site url and you will get all post.

for get all post

```
www.mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

For the search functionality - search test post

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[s]=test
```

much more details from this link http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/

Note for best result use latest version of WP

so using this you can easily get post page etc.

Comment: how can i get cookie var in jquery ?

Comment: you need to call url and in response you will get cookie var.